# Config file location for Civlization V on Linux

Tags: civilization-5, linux, steam-os

On Linux-family systems, where are the files that store user configuration (particularly pertaining to resolution) found?

I've been looking over the usual suspects (`~/.steam`, the game installation directory) without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in `~/.local/share/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5/UserSettings.ini`

I had to run `find` to locate it.

Comment: Thanks! It hasn't occurred to me to search there, for some reason. FYI, the graphics settings are actually located in `GraphicsSettingsDX9.ini`, on the same path.

Comment: Oh. I was looking for UserSettings.ini when you asked that, because I wanted to disable the introduction video. So, coincidentally, I found your question.

Comment: and then the answer, which is great :).